# Some of the objects in a Julia Package are not defined

Tags: julia

I am using Julia 1.8.1 in windows 10.

I add the SumOfSquare Package, but some of the objects are not defined.
For example, if I run:

```
using SumOfSquares
Symmetry
```

I get the error: UndefVarError: Symmetry not defined

I have updated the package, removed and then added it again, but none of them works.

However, I tested this in Linux, and it's totally fine in Linux.

What is the reason?

What should I do?

Comment: It works on your Linux and on Windows 10 / Julia 1.8.1 here, so I would try reinstalling and or rebuilding SumOfSquares.

Comment: @Bill Do you know how I can uninstall Julia so that nothing related to it would be left? Uninstallation does not help because Julia's packages are still on my pc after uninstallation.

Comment: Inside of Julia you can look at `DEPOT_PATH` and delete any directories in that list that exist. Probably only the first one will exist.